# How does enterprise failover, such as with google.com, actually work?

Tags: linux, cloud, failover, redundancy

We have a few fedora systems that are configured for web, FTP, and email services. We'd like to mirror these services, so that we can provide near 100% reliability for our users. I'm a fairly experienced Linux administrator, but don't have much experience with redundant systems.

What is the best way to do this? How does google and amazon do it? Google.com resolves to multiple IP addresses, but if my local desktop caches one of the IPs that are unreachable, I'm going to get a failed connection message. How do they prevent that from happening?

If one of their servers goes down, how is it automatically redirected to another system, without the end-user ever knowing it?

I understand there are failover devices, but they're only for failing over the system itself, not a complete network.

Let's say we have the worst-case scenario, such as my primary system becomes inaccessible. What are the fundamental components that are used on Linux systems to provide this capability?

I'm looking for concepts, or approaches, not answers like "check out openstack". What are the actual pieces that make up the solution? What has to be done to implement this capability?

Comment: Interesting - but usually the job of sysadmins/netadmins to worry about, so Off Topic it is :)

Comment: Have you checked at the sister site serverfault.com? This sounds like something that could get some good answers there.

Answer (score 2):

Google or Amazon published IP addresses are not really their servers, but load balancers. Load balancer dynamically forwards incoming client connections to actual servers, and it could be hundreds and thousands of them behind single IP address.

You might ask what if load balancer itself goes down?
Well, they typically work clustered - at least 2, and all share the same virtual IP address. If one goes down, virtual IP still appears to be working, because another member of this load balancer cluster is still serving that request.

If clustered load balancer goes down still, they automatically change their DNS such that this virtual IP is not advertized to DNS clients anymore. To make it fast, typical TTL on these IP is set rather low, few minutes or less (for google.com it is 5 minutes).

Of course, reality is little bit more complicated than this, but it should give you rough idea.